# Is second countability an extension property for non-Hausdorff spaces?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian topological group and let $H$ be a non-Hausdorff closed subgroup (so that $G/H$ *is* Hausdorff). If $H$ and $G/H$ are second countable, is $G$ second countable?

Comment: Your title is about  spaces but the question is about topological groups. Anyway, a topological group is always extension of a indiscrete subgroup (the closure of $\{1\}$) by a Hausdorff, and in particular, $G$ is 2nd-countable iff its maximal Hausdorff quotient is second countable. The answer to your question hence thus clearly boils down to the case when $G$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Dear YCor, many thanks for your answer. It is exactly what I needed. In Hewitt and Ross, Abstract Harmonic Analysis I, (5.38)(e), p.47, a proof is given ( independently of any separation hypotheses) of the stated result for first-countability

Comment: The proof alluded to is an adaptation of a 1950 argument by Graev (apparently only in Russian), cited 4, p.497 of the Hewitt-Ross book. As explained on p.30 of   «Metric Geometry of Locally Compact Groups» (a book that you might know very well), the required property for second-countability then follows from certain other results which, unfortunately, depend on the Hausdorff hypothesis. I work in Number Theory, where non-Hausdorff 
group quotients appear often, so I often regret that many excellent texts make this Hausdorff blanket hypothesis right from the start.